# circular enemy aggro condition ? (2D game in pure JS)

Tags: javascript, artificial-intelligence

I'm struggling to code a circular-shaped detection area for enemies aggro detection. Currently, enemies are pulled if the player x and y position collide with the enemy x and y position plus and minus its aggroDist.

Here is the current code :

```
if (player.x > enemies[e].x -enemies[e].aggroDist && 
    player.x < enemies[e].x +enemies[e].aggroDist && 
    player.y > enemies[e].y -enemies[e].aggroDist && 
    player.y < enemies[e].y +enemies[e].aggroDist) {
        enemies[e].isAggro = true;
        console.log(enemies[e].isAggro);
    }
```

Problem with this approach is the square-shaped detection area, meaning that the enemy can detect the player at a farther distance on the diagonals edges.

[image]

I tried to make a circular-shaped detection area using something like `enemies[e].x + (enemies[e].aggroDist * Math.PI)` but I have no idea how to implement it (maybe because this approach is wrong too).

Any idea how I can make all the distances between the center of the detection area and its border strictly equals to each other ?

Comment: you want to know if the red dot is inside the circle?

Comment: [`Math.hypot(dx, dy)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/hypot) (Look up "Pythagorean theorem" or "distance formula")

Comment: Could you use the distance formular from centerpoint of each entity use that as "aggroDist"?

http://www.purplemath.com/modules/distform.htm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a rough implementation using a distance formula:

```js
//Load HTML elements
var c = document.getElementById("c");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
//Distance function 
function distance(x1, y1, x2, y2) {
    return Math.sqrt((x2 -= x1) * x2 + (y2 -= y1) * y2);
}
//Entity is the player, radius is the aggro distance
var entity = { x: 200, y: 200, radius: 50 };
//Radius is the aggro distance of the other entities
var radius = 2;
//Draw player
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.arc(entity.x, entity.y, entity.radius, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
ctx.stroke();
ctx.closePath();
//Loop through "X" and "Y" combinations and draw "enemies"
for (var x = 0; x < 400; x += 10) {
    for (var y = 0; y < 400; y += 10) {
        //Get distance between "enemy" and "player"
        var d = distance(x, y, entity.x, entity.y);
        //If the distance is less than the combined aggro distances, turn red, else turn green
        ctx.strokeStyle = (d < entity.radius + radius ? "red" : "green");
        //Draw enemy
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.arc(x, y, radius, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
        ctx.stroke();
        ctx.closePath();
    }
}
```

```html
<canvas id="c" height="400" width="400"></canvas>
```

Comment: very elegant solution, works like a charm ! Thank you !